# Is a string equal to any of its previous lags in the given grouping

Tags: r

I am trying to determine whether *string* is equal to any of its previous lags for a group given by *id*. The number of occurences of each group is unknown to us. Preferably using dplyr.

Example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2), string = c('a','b','b','a','a','a','b'))
```

The result is expected to be like this:

```
c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: You are looking for `duplicated`, i.e. `!!with(df, ave(id, string, FUN = duplicated))`

Comment: Would that not return TRUE even if the duplicated occurs after the current observation? I need to check observations preceding the current one

Comment: Actually you are right, I did not understand how the ave() function works

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @Sotos, the correct answer is:

```
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
anybefore = ave(id, string, FUN = duplicated)
```